# radicals and rational exponents. simplifying $4^{5/3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

This question is not for homework.

The book says:

$$4^{5/3} = (\sqrt4)^5 = (\sqrt{2^2})^5 = 2^5 = 32$$

when a bunch of us tried it:

$$4^{5/3} = \sqrt[3]{4^5} = \sqrt[3]{2^3 \cdot 2^2} = 2 \cdot \sqrt[3]{2^2} = 2 \cdot \sqrt[3]{4}$$

I get the sense we missed something. Where did we mess it up? We don't know how to get to 32.

Comment: Note that your own calculation is wrong - reality check $4^{\frac 53} \gt 4$ while $2\cdot \sqrt[3] 4 \lt 4$ - you could go via $2^{\frac {10}3}=2^{3+\frac 13}$

Comment: this is what has been very frustrating about rational exponents and radicals, so many routes, so many ways, so many things to simplify.. so many approaches. how does one know which to choose? and when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a typo in your book, since
$$(\sqrt 4)^5 = 4^{5/2}\neq 4^{5/3}.$$

However, you still made a mistake in your calculation. You replaced $4^5$ with $2^3\cdot 2^2$, when in reality, $4^5 = 4^3\cdot 4^2 = 2^6 \cdot 2^4$.

Comment: oh, mabye its time to get a supplementary book. can see now it is very wrong, but when wrote $2^{3} \cdot 2^{2}$ it seemed so right.

Answer (score 2):

Your book is wrong. $$4^{5/3}\neq (\sqrt4)^5$$